# anchor (#) in url alias

Tags: 7, uri, path-aliases, navigation

I want to open same page from different contents. So I need to generate link like `/testimonials#group-1` for these contents. I used pathauto module for this. I made pattern for this category `testimonials#[node:title]`. But this URL get encoded by browser `/testimonials%23group-1` and it gives me no page found error.

So how can I put anchor (#) in URL alias which can give me output like `/testimonials#group-1`.?

Comment: Why would you be using pathauto for this? It is not actually part of the "path", since it is only an anchor. We will be needing more info about where you are trying to implement this.

Comment: @NeverQuit Please read Ambidex's comment. Fragments are not part of the path, it doesn't make sense to add a fragment to a URL alias (and you can't do it). You should add the fragment to the end of a URL in a **link** that points to the path

Comment: @Ambidex I'm using this at one of my content->URL path settings-> URL alias = "testimonials#group-1". But browser encode '#' to %23 so it gives an error.

Comment: I can think of a few instances were having a fragment as part of the pathalias would make sense.  Like when you have nodes that never live on their own, but are always part of a view.

Comment: @MPD From a "this is what I'd like" point of view it does make sense, but from a practical standpoint it's not implementable. Ambidex's answer goes a good way towards explaining why that is

Comment: @MPD That would be a piece of "logics" implementation for your summary of nodes, it still is not a reference to your node itself but a position in a summary of nodes, so that should not be in a path (nor alias).

Comment: I've got a site where I don't want to display nodes directly. All nodes are in Views, on my site i've got search form. Search results gives me direct links to nodes, i want to modify them to point to page with View which contains searched node. I also want to move user to this node using anchor. This is my idea, You tell i can't do it this way so which way i can achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

I think you are trying to add anchors to a node's alias to define multiple sections in a node, which is *impossible* since an **anchor destination** is not part of a **path** and therefor not part of an **alias**. For more information, see the [W3 introduction on links in HTML](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/links.html).

**Creating a anchor**: If you would like to subsection your node's body, you should use anchors in your code:

```
<a name="anchorOne"> ... </a>
```

If you're using the [WYSIWYG module](http://drupal.org/project/wysiwyg), make sure you've got the `Anchor` plugin enabled, so you can create the anchors through the nicely builtin anchor plugin's GUI, which makes it that much easier.

**Linking to an anchor**: After creating an anchor, you can link to that section by making a hyperlink as follows:

```
<a href="/path/to/node#anchorOne">Link text</a>
```

To build the above link in the Drupal-way:

```
<?php print l('Link text', 'path/to/node', array('fragment' => 'anchorOne')); ?>
```

Or to only build the URL including the anchor destination:

```
<?php print url('path/to/node', NULL, 'anchorOne'); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's called a [fragment identifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier), and is done with the [l() function](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/l/7):

```
$options = array('fragment' => 'group-1');
l('Anchor', 'path', $options);
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, set the Pathauto pattens for the content type **testimonial** to */testimonials/[node:title]*. This could later on be useful if you display one testimonial as a node, for instance if you don't include the full node in the view below.

Then create a view that lists all your testimonials, and show them as a page on the URL */testimonials*. Use the style Unformatted, and make sure you include the Title in the rows class (using the "Style > Style > Settings" in views), you could be use **Anchor-[title]** (show you later on why the 'Anchor_'-part).

Then make a special versions of the views-view-unformatted.tpl.php (eg. views-view-unformatted--.tpl.php) and put it in your own themes folder (where it fits).

```
<?php foreach ($rows as $id => $row): ?>
  <div <?php if ($classes_array[$id]) { print 'class="' . $classes_array[$id] .'"';  } ?>>
    <?php print $row; ?>
  </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Make a small PHP snippet that fetches the rows styles and then find the one class that contains the "Anchor-Title".

```
<?php foreach ($rows as $id => $row): ?>
  <div <?php if ($classes_array[$id]) { print 'class="' . $classes_array[$id] .'"';  } ?>>
    <?php
      if ($classes_array[$id]) {
        $classes = explode(" ", $classes_array[$id]);
        for ($i=0;$i<count();$i++) {
          if (strpos($classes[$i], "Anchor_") === 0) {
            list($tmp, $anchor) = explode("_", $classes[$i]);
    ?>
    <a name="<?php print $anchor; ?>"></a>
    <?php
          }   
        }
      }
    ?>
    <?php print $row; ?>
  </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Perhaps the code can be optimized, but that's only something to get you started...

BTW: To create a "menu" on the top, you could add a header to the view that's containing a view that makes links out of titles. Eg.

```
  <a href="#Title">Link text</a>
```